# How to intersect on same table dynamically

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a table (city, country). I want to only get cities that are common in all countries.

```
create table #cities(city nvarchar(10), country nvarchar(10))

insert into #cities(city, country)
select 'NY', 'US' UNION
select 'London', 'UK' UNION
select 'London', 'US'


select city from #cities where country = 'US'
intersect
select city from #cities where country = 'UK'
```

How can I achieve this dynamically and preferably without cursors if the list of countries is not known upfront.

Comment: Does intersect not work for you?

Comment: I am not sure how I would use intersect if I do not know the list of countries. Say I start with `select distinct country from #cities`, then the only option I see is to use a cursor to keep intersecting. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Then The Impaler's answer will work for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select city
from #cities
group by city
having count(*) = (select count(distinct country) from #cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello or you can use a self join like this and it will give the right output

```
  SELECT DISTINCT A.CITY FROM CITIES A
    JOIN CITIES B ON  A.CITY =B.CITY AND A.COUNTRY<>B.COUNTRY;
```

Hope it helps